How do I change the default DVD burn path in Windows?
I am trying to burn files to a DVD but I am encountering cases of "destination path too long".  When I look at my source files, the paths are within the 255 character limit, but close to it.
I have discovered that Windows, in fact, stores these in a temporary area at C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn and I believe that it is this long path name that puts my path names over the edge.
I tried using mklink, as suggested at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-change-the-temporary-cd-burning-folder/49b26b6f-3679-4a9a-b480-2130f0529b2f, to link this to a much shorter D:\Burn path.  But this does not seem to help.  The burner still sees the temporary files in the C:\Users...\Burn location.
Does anyone know how to tell Windows to use a different temporary location for DVD burning?

“Does anyone know how to tell Windows to use a different temporary location for DVD burning?” - You cannot; However, the entire path to the file isn’t copied only the files, have you tried moving the file and then trying creating the media?

After inserting the DVD (G: drive), I try copying the files over to the empty G: drive.  The copy grinds away for a bit and then stops with a message along the lines of a file or folder path is too long with Skip or Cancel.  The actual files that I am copying are not too long to fit on an empty drive.  But I notice that the actual path in File Explorer points to the C:\Users...\Burn folder.  So I am assuming that Windows is complaining because it can't accommodate the additional path length created by the C:\Users...\Burn folder.

I see there are several registry keys that point to this folder but in a couple forums I've looked at, changing these didn't seem to help.

Unless the file names and folder names and the files within those files, the path to those directories and files are not used, they are copied to the temporary directory you have identified which is well within the restrictions. Something else is going on.

Okay, so I seem to have solved my problem.

just to confirm that my directory structure was copyable, I created a small directory D:\Test and copy-pasted my files over to that w/o any issues.
I created a new folder D:\Burn
I edited the following registry keys:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CD Burning\StagingInfo\Volume{*}\StagingPath
HEKY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\CD Burning
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\CD BUrning

These keys were all originally the long path C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn, with various subfolders.  I changed all of these to D:\Burn.
There were a number of other registry keys that had the long path in them, but they all had "Windows Search" in the registry path, so I assumed they were all related to doing a search in Windows Explorer, and I left them alone.
I then rebooted my machine just to make sure I hadn't hosed my registry beyond recognition.
Looking at my D: drive, I now observe the D:\Burn folder as well as a new hidden folder, "D:\Temporary Burn Folder" which, when I look at it's properties, I noticed a Location tab that has D:\Burn as it's value.
So now, I put a new disk in my drive and copy-pasted my directory over to the empty G: drive.
The copy succeeded without incident.  But I observed by selecting on one of the files, that now the Windows Explorer now shows D:\Burn in the title bar where before it had displayed C:\Users\...\Burn in the title bar.
Burning the files to disk then also executed without incident.
So, it appears that the Windows Disk Burner, creates this temporary burn folder in the User directory.  When dragging files to a blank DVD/CD/BlueRay/etc., Windows actually tries to put all of these in a Temporary Burn Folder which is mapped to C:\Users\...\Burn.  Hence, the too-long-path complaint.
So the solution was to tell Windows to use a different, shorter, location for the temporary files by editing the registry.
All right...  a couple more lessons learned:
By default, Windows places the temporary burn folders in C:\Users\...\Burn.
There will be a folder for each optical drive:
C:\Users\...\Burn\Burn1
C:\Users\...\Burn\Burn2
and so on.
If you add another drive, e.g. an external DVD drive, Windows will create a new folder under the Burn folder:
C:\Users\...\Burn\Burn3
In my original solution above, I just created D:\Burn and updated my registry settings to point to that.  The problem is that the registry assumed that this was for a particular drive.  It assumed that D:\ was the area where each drive folder (e.g. Burn2) so Windows started complaining that there were still files left to be burned to disk (i.e. each folder in my D:.
The final solution was to create D:\Burn\Burn1 and then point my registry settings to that.  For each volume noted in the registry, I needed to create another subfolder under D:\Burn and point to that.
Now, plugging in my external drive, D:\Burn\Burn2 shows up.  Although looking at Windows Explorer now, it shows "D:\Burn\Temporary Burn Folder" and "D:\Burn\Temporary Burn Folder" (with each of these being some kind of shell folder that actually points to D:\Burn\Burn1, D:\Burn\Burn2, etc.
Final answer:
Create D:\Burn\Burn1 and use this for the registry settings for the keys mentioned above.  In the registry StaginInfo area, each element points to a different subfolder under D:\Burn.
